# How to monitor java code level generated statistics efficiently?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, monitoring, yammer

I am dealing with one of the critical software service in our java web application.

We wanted to monitor the java code level statistics(**eg.** Mean rate, avg rate and number of order received in system) for our web application so that we can understand that what is going on inside the java code and we can take steps early to rectify them.

There are plenty of open source application monitoring API's are available on internet for this purpose. We have looked into **Yammer metrics** and **Jamon API(Source forge)**.

But there are some common concerns regarding these all open source projects :

- If we incorporate these API's in our main application code base, then it will generate statistics data which can acquire memory on the system. This can lead to potential issues like system breakdown or performance degradation.
- In our system we need to capture whole statistics data which was generated since the starting. So somehow we need to continuously stream the generated data to some other server so that it is not saved on main system memory.

We always wanted to implement this performance monitoring system which is loosely coupled from our main application code. In short we cannot claim any memory inside the main application server, because that can shut down the whole business.

I searched internet a lot but cannot find an efficient solution.

Comment: Why would storing a few numbers in memory shut down the whole business? Try thinking scientifically. Recording statistics will have an impact on the performance and memory consumption of the app. Every monitoring software obviously knows that and tries to reduce this impact as much as possible. But of course, it won't shut down the whole business, because if it did, no-one would use them.

Comment: **Any** change you make to your Java web application can shut down the whole business.  I'm assuming you have a test system, right?  Add the metrics to your system, test them, and see what impact they have.